# Expected and Actual results are the same but test fail

Tags: unit-testing

```
[TestMethod]
        public void PutStringTest()
        {
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            Console.SetOut(stringWriter);

            ui.PutString("Test");

            Assert.AreEqual(stringWriter.ToString(), "Test\n");
        }
```

PutString is a simple Console.Writeline();

```
        public void PutString(string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

Assert.AreEqual failed.
Expected:. Actual:.

This is a MS Test Case that fails even tho it should been green. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The assert fails because they are different reference. To check strings, you should use this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(stringWriter.ToString().Equals("Test\n");
```

Anyway, the reason is in the output of that test